# Resizing Font Awesome Fonts with font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been trying to take two font images of a lock and stack them on top of each other. Then, I wanted to resize one of them slightly so it looks like there is a border wrapped around the bottom one. However, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to size it properly and I dont understand why font-size isn't working as expected. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/4LqeN/1694/

```css
i
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
}

#lock-black{
  font-size: 200%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i id="lock-black" class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-2x "></i>
  <i id="lock=blue" class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x" style="color:blue" ></i>
</span>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do... it looks like your blue lock is within the black one. The blue one appears to be about half the size of your blue one, which makes sense given `font-size:200%` on `#lock-black`. Note that you have a syntax error in the id for the blue lock; it should be a dash, not equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```css
i
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
}

#lock-black{
  font-size: 200%;
}

#lock-blue{
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i id="lock-black" class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-2x "></i>
  <i id="lock-blue" class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x" style="color:blue" ></i>
</span>
```